# How to convert user input to string in python 2.7

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, user-input, nameerror

When I enter

`username = str(input("Username:"))`

`password = str(input("Password:"))`

and after running the program, I fill in the input with my name and hit enter

`username = sarang`

I get the error

`NameError: name 'sarang' is not defined`

I have tried

`username = '"{}"'.format(input("Username:"))`

and

`password = '"{}"'.format(input("Password:"))`

but I end up getting the same error.

How do I convert the input into a string and fix the error?

Answer (score 8):

Use `raw_input()` in Python 2.x and `input()` in Python 3.x to get a string.

You have two choices: run your code via Python 3.x or change `input()` to `raw_input()` in your code.

Python 2.x `input()` evaluates the user input as code, not as data. It looks for a variable in your existing code called `sarang` but fails to find it; thus a `NameError` is thrown.

Side note: you could add this to your code and call `input_func()` instead. It will pick the right input method automatically so your code will work the same in Python 2.x and 3.x:

```
input_func = None
try:
    input_func = raw_input
except NameError:
    input_func = input

# test it

username = input_func("Username:")
print(username)
```

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x) for more details.

Comment: the problem is fixed thanks to your help

Comment: @sarang.g Nice, you’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly use raw_input(prompt), instead of just using input(prompt).
As you are currently using Python 2.x which supports this type of formatting for receiving an input from user.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2, `raw_input()` returns a string, and `input()` tries to run the input as a Python expression.

Since getting a string was almost always what you wanted, Python 3 does that with `input()`.